# Replace the even characters to upper case and the remaining characters to lower case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an SQL query to replace the even characters to upper case and the remaining characters to lower case in a string?

For example if the string is 'sagar' the result should be like

```
sAgAr
```

What would be the appropriate solution for this?

Comment: Maybe my tea hasn't kicked in, is there a question?

Comment: Instead of printing you want to generate rows?

Comment: You have posted working code, I don't see a question

Comment: This is a working code which I have faced in one of my Interviews and just wanted to update to users since I haven't got this answer in any blogs

Comment: then you should move your answer to an answer, instead of having it in your question

Comment: ok moving the answer in answer section. thanks for the update

Comment: request you to please verify the result and suggest me if there is any better answer for this

Comment: As an interview question, you should first consider the intent of the question. Is it really intended to demonstrate a particular tsql skill or is it intended to determine your general level of problem solving. You should realize that tsql is not well designed to implement this logic - and you should have asked more questions in response. In addition, this is a completely nonsense question - I can't think of any reasonable goal that this would satisfy. So perhaps that should have been your first response - why would anyone want to do this in any language.

Comment: It was asked to see the general level of problem solving. I think this might be asked to check the knowledge of predefined function (SUBSTRING, UPPER and LOWER) of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't resist answering.  This seems like such a natural for a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select 'abcdef' as str
     ),
     cte as (
      select cast(lower(str) as varchar(max)) as str, 1 as pos
      from t
      union all
      select stuff(str, pos + 1, 1,
                   (case when pos % 2 = 1 then upper(substring(str, pos + 1, 1))
                         else lower(substring(str, pos + 1, 1))
                    end)
                   ) as str, 1 + pos
      from cte
      where pos < len(str)
     )
select top (1) *
from cte
order by pos desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Written the below code and it works fine

Tested on Master DB

```
declare @name nvarchar(50)
declare @i int
set @i=1
set @name='sagar'
while(@i<=LEN(@name))
begin
if(@i%2=0)
    begin
        print Upper(SUBSTRING(@name,@i,1))
        set @i=@i+1
    end
else
    begin
        print Lower(SUBSTRING(@name,@i,1))
        set @i=@i+1
    end
end
```

Give the name of your own choice while setting the @name parameter and you can get the required result

Comment: Consistency is the mark of a good developer. You defined @name as nvarchar but you used an ascii literal for assignment. You should also be terminating your statements. Lastly, your code does not "work fine" because it prints a single letter at a time. It could easily be changed to print the correct value once - but you chose differently.

Comment: Just to add on to @SMor most SQL Server interview questions are looking for set based approaches instead of *looping* methodology which is fast in most OOP and scripting languages, but not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Using a tally table...

```
declare @table table ([name] varchar(64))
insert into @table
values 
('sAgAr')
,('abcdefghijk')
,('LMNOPQ')

;WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )


select 
    t.[name]
    ,lower(left(t.[name],1))
     + 
     STUFF((
        SELECT '' + case 
                        when c2.N%2 = 0 then upper(substring(t2.[name],c2.N,1)) 
                        else lower(substring(t2.[name],c2.N,1)) 
                    end
        FROM @table t2
        cross apply cteTally c2
        where 
            len(t2.[name]) >= c2.N
            and t2.name = t.name
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from
    @table t
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by splitting into rows and recreating strings again:

```
declare @test table ([value] nvarchar(20))
insert into @test values ('sagar'), ('Blueprint'), ('turtLe')

;with cte as (
    select [value]
        , num
        , iif(num % 2 = 0, upper(substring([value], num, 1)), lower(substring([value], num, 1))) as [char]
    from @test
    cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) numbers(num) --add more for > 12 characters
    where num <= len([Value]))
select distinct [Value], [CaseApplied] = STUFF(( SELECT '' + [char]
                FROM    cte AS c
                WHERE c.[value]= cte.value
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 0, '')
from cte
```

Comment: This is similar to my method, except i use a tally table instead of the table constructor so the number of values you have to cross join to is dynamic. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @mystringLOW varchar(100) = 'sagar'
       ,@pos int = 2

WHILE @pos <= LEN(@mystringLOW)
BEGIN
SET @mystringLOW = (SELECT STUFF(@mystringLOW, @pos, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@mystringLOW, @pos, 1))))
SET @pos += 2
END

SELECT @mystringLOW AS [my answer]
```

Produces:

```
my answer
---------
sAgAr
```